# Python dependency management using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am looking for a good solution to manage Python dependencies within AWS lambda.

**Simplified project setup:**

- 3 projects
- seperated in git repos
- deployment managed by terraform
- commons.py is duplicated in each repo
- commons.py is part of lamda deployment zip

```
--- git repo of project A
------ lambda.py
--------- commons.py in version 1

--- git repo of project B
------ lambda.py
--------- commons.py in version 1

--- git repo of project c
------ lambda.py
--------- commons.py in version 2
```

**Main goals:**

- avoid duplication of commons.py
- ensure local testing
- in case of bugfixing, fix commons.py one time
- in case of bugfixing, provide new version of commons.py one time

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem you can package your `commons.py` and host it in pypi (or a private repository, e.g. [github](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-github-as-a-pypi-server-1c3b0d07db2/) or [gemfury](https://gemfury.com/)). Then you'll just need to install it with pip like any other package.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AWS lambda layers for the same where you can upload your code as a layer and can be used by different lambdas. Aws lambda layer is a free tool that can help to reduce code redundancy. Let me know in case you face any problems using this.